# img and text vertical align

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="card">
<img class='sound' src='https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png'>
<div class='txt'>
 this is a sentence.this is a sentencethis is a sentence.
 </div></div>

.card{
    margin:5px 14px;
    border:thin solid blue;
}
.sound{
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.txt{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:25px;
    vertical-align:middle;  //doesn't work
    border:thin solid red;
}
```

How can I align `.txt` div to be on the middle of `.sound` image ?
fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hWejY/)

Comment: Solved, thanks to everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put vertical-align on `.sound`?

```
.card{
    margin:5px 14px;
    border:thin solid blue;
}
.sound{
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    cursor:pointer;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.txt{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:25px;
    border:thin solid red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hWejY/1/

Answer (score 1):

Insert `vertical-align: middle` into class sound

```
.card{
    margin:5px 14px;
    border:thin solid blue;
}
.sound{
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    cursor:pointer;
    vertical-align:middle
}
.txt{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:25px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border:thin solid red;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hWejY/2/)

Answer (score 1):

```
vertical-align:middle;
```

Should be on .sound